# Wrong Output while Printing maximum in linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, max, singly-linked-list

I was printing the max of a linked list in C++ language . But I was not getting the desired output. While Building and running the code, the terminal gets stuck in building it. I tried it in VS Code and Sublime text both. I am using mingw64 compiler.

After the run the program this happens [Gets stuck after displaying the linked list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAFkK.png)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *first = NULL;

//declaring a global head/first pointer which stores the address of first node

void create(int a[], int n) {
    int i;
    struct node *t, *last;
    first = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    first->data = a[0];
    first->next = NULL;
    last = first;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        // t = new node;
        t = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->data = a[i];
        t->next = NULL;
        last->next = t;
        last = t;
    }
}

void display(struct node *p) {
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int Max(struct node *p) {
    int max = -100;
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->data > max) {
            max = p->data;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main() {
    int m = 0;
    int a[] = { 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 8, 12, 20 };
    create(a, 8);
    display(first);
    printf("\n");
    m = Max(first);
    cout << "The maximum of the linked list is : " << m;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your `Max()` you only proceed to the next element if the current one is the local maximum.

Comment: This looks rather more like C than C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo It's a mixture -- it uses both `printf` and `cout`.

Comment: Take `p = p->next;` out of the `if` block.

Comment: The `Max` loop in English: "If `p->data` is greater than the current maximum, store it as the new maximum and move to the next element. Otherwise, do nothing and keep looping." You can see the problem now.

Comment: Ohkay thanks  for the help such a silly mistake i should have added the p = p->next after the if block.

Comment: FYI, in C++ you don't need the `struct` keyword when declaring variables or parameters.  Which language are you programming in?  Please update your language tags.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, prefer to use `new` than `malloc`.  The `malloc` function doesn't call constructors.

Answer (score 6):

```
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->data > max)
        {
            max = p->data;
            p = p->next;
        }

    }
```

Update this to

```
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->data > max)
        {
            max = p->data;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
```

Otherwise your code will STUCK in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer one line comparison so that code is easy to understand and no bus will appear

```
int Max(struct node *p) {
    int max_number = INT_MIN;
    while (p != NULL) {
         max_number = max(max_number, p->data);
         p = p->next;
    }
     
    return max_number;
}
```

Comment: You might want to include `<limits.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mixture of C and C++ code. You should settle for one or the other and use idioms appropriate for the one you choose. Using a mixture of C and C++ is a recipe for failure. As coded, the program is closer to C than C++, just remove the *C++isms* and program in C.

The reason it gets *stuck* is `p` does not get updated in the `while` loop when the value `p->data` is not greater than `max`. Note however that there are other problems: the code will not find the maximum value if all values are less than `-100` and it will return `-100` if the list is empty.

Here is a modified version, in C, with both issues corrected:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//declaring a global head/first pointer which stores the address of first node
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *first = NULL;

/* append the elements from a[] to the end of the linked list */
void create(const int a[], int n) {
    struct node *last;

    last = first;
    while (last && last->next) {
        last = last->next;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // t = new node;
        struct node *t = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (t == NULL)
            return;
        t->data = a[i];
        t->next = NULL;
        if (last)
            last->next = t;
        else
            first = t;
        last = t;
    }
}

void display(const struct node *p) {
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int getmax(struct node *p) {
    int max = 0;
    if (p != NULL) {
        max = p->data;
        p = p->next;
        while (p != NULL) {
            if (max < p->data) {
                max = p->data;
            }
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 8, 12, 20 };
    create(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));
    display(first);
    printf("The maximum of the linked list is: %d\n", getmax(first));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Except these two lines

```
using namespace std;
```

and

```
cout << "The maximum of the linked list is : " << m;
```

there is nothing in the program that could be referenced as a C++ code and not C code. Moreover you even forgot to include the header `<iostream>`.

Also the program has an inconsistence interface. Some functions deal directly with the global variable `first` while other functions accept the variable through parameters.

Even the function `create` can invoke undefined behavior because the user can pass as the second argument zero or a negative number.

```
void create(int a[], int n) {
    int i;
    struct node *t, *last;
    first = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    first->data = a[0];
    //...
```

In this case the expression `a[0]` has an indeterminate value.

The function `Max` (Why does its name start with an upper case letter?) has a bug. Moving to a next node occurs only in case when `p->data > max`

```
    if (p->data > max) {
        max = p->data;
        p = p->next;
    }
```

You need to place the statement

```
p = p->next;
```

after the if statement

```
int Max(struct node *p) {
    int max = -100;
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->data > max) {
            max = p->data;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    return max;
}
```

But in any case the function does not make a great sense because the returned value `-100` for an empty list can be a valid data for the list.

If you are learning C++ then start to learn it from the C++ 17 Standard and use features of C++ instead of features of C as the C++ operator new instead of the C function malloc.

Your program as indeed a C++ program can look for example the following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void clear( node * &head )
{
    while ( head ) delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
}

void create( node *&head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    clear( head );

    node **current = &head;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *current = new node{ a[i], nullptr };
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }
}

std::ostream &display( const node *head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for (const node *current = head; current; current = current->next)
    {
        os << current->data << " -> ";
    }

    return os << "null";
}

std::optional<int> max( const node *head )
{
    std::optional<int> max_value;

    if (head)
    {
        max_value = head->data;

        for (const node *current = head->next; current; current = current->next)
        {
            if (max_value < current->data) max_value = current->data;
        }
    }

    return max_value;
}

int main()
{
    node *head = nullptr;

    int a[] = { 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 8, 12, 20 };

    create( head, a, std::size( a ) );

    display( head ) << '\n';

    auto max_value = max( head );

    if ( max_value )
    {
        std::cout << "The maximum of the linked list is : " << *max_value << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The list is empty.\n";
    }

    clear( head );

    max_value = max( head );

    if ( max_value )
    {
        std::cout << "The maximum of the linked list is : " << *max_value << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The list is empty.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 10 -> 15 -> 8 -> 12 -> 20 -> null
The maximum of the linked list is : 20
The list is empty.
```